# How do you import a nested package via string?

Tags: python, import, python-module, python-importlib

I'm trying to dynamically import a package which is a subdirectory of another package.

Though there is no [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) about it, this doesn't seem to be possible with `importlib`.

Example:
Start with

```
pip install pytest
```

then,

```
import importlib
mod = importlib.import_module("pytester", package="_pytest")
```

fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytester'`, while

```
from _pytest import pytester
```

succeeds.

```
import importlib
mod = importlib.__import__("_pytest.pytester")
```

also succeed, but returns the `_pytest` module, not the `pytester` module, and I don't seem to have a way of accessing `mod.pytester` by string.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'package' argument of [`import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) is used for relative imports.

Instead, the equivalent of `from _pytest import pytester` would be:

```
pytester = importlib.import_module("_pytest.pytester")
```

Note that this module is *not* a public API of pytest, as indicated by the leading underscore. It's pytest's own business to import the `pytester` submodule, users shouldn't need to do this - the public API is using the [pytester fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=pytester#pytester) which does not require you to import anything.

Comment: That was it, thanks. I didn't realize that the "module name" arg accepted the full module path. BTW, `pytest` was just a convenient and publicly available example because I don't want to post my entire nested packages.